# Add UItableview on UIVisualEffectView using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add `UItableview` on `UIVisualEffectView`. I have coded like below

```
 // MainView 
  Mainview = [[UIView alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubview:Mainview];

  blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
  visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
  [visualEffectView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
  [self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];

  table = [[UITableView alloc]init];
  table.scrollEnabled = YES;
  table.allowsSelection = YES;
  table.dataSource = self;
  table.delegate = self;
  table.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
  table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  table.bounces = YES;
  [table setBackgroundView:nil];
  [table setOpaque:NO];
  [table setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
  [table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,500) animated:YES];
  [visualEffectView.contentView addSubview: table];
```

Whenever I am `scrolling tableview` suddenly `UIVisualEffectView` hiding. Nothing `error` I have faced. I need to build stable `UIVisualEffectView`.

Comment: do u want to make ur tableview background blur OR cell blur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

remove this line

```
 [self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

and add here

```
[visualEffectView.contentView addSubview: table];
[self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

Comment: Same problem. while I am scrolling tableview its evrything totally hidden. Nothing error also.@Anbu

Comment: which one bro and add the background color for visualeffectview and check once and I have a doubt where is your tableview.frame

Comment: Tableview frame I had successfully added on UIVisualEffectiveView. Now the problem is while I am scrolling tableview cell, suddenly hiding UIVisualEffectiveView.@Anbu

Comment: Hidden logics to I have successfully completed. Anyway your idea aso usefull. thank you dude!

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the UITableView above the effectView and set the background color of tableView clear color? I think it will look the same.